# Will I put my US visa chance in risk if I make a (funny) website about the President tweets?

Tags: usa, visa-rejections, us-visa

I have made a website which shows the President Trump's tweets along with some funny stickers (just funny, not rude!). I was wondering publishing that website and put a link on my portfolio to demonstrate my skills.

But I am worried that such a website affects my future chance of getting the USA visa (for conferences, or even applying for green card). Will the officers care about that even if they find it? Note that my country of citizenship is already under sanctions by the US (the famous ban act).

Comment: How funny we talking?  Screenshots? ;)

Comment: Can you clarify which visa you intend to apply for? Green card is technically not a visa and they can use your website against you in a green card application/interview/background check.

Comment: Leaving aside freedom of speech, if you have any thoughts at all about visiting / getting a green card in the future, AND you are a citizen of a sanctioned country, AND you say you’re worried about it affecting your chances, why would you want to do this? Even if what you publish is ‘acceptable’ now, it might not be in the future.

Answer (score 7):

You may think the content is funny, but others (like US State Department staff) who see your webpage might feel or think differently. And it's not unreasonable to think they'll look harder at applicants from a "banned" country than those applicants coming from somewhere else.

There are no rules of which I'm aware that say what weight, if any, is to be given to an applicant's online statements. However, I'd say that having a website with political content — especially political content directed at the US or its institutions, or one that pokes fun at them — runs a significant risk of being counted against you.

Comment: In what way would it be counted against the OP? Consular officers are not allowed to discriminate based on religious or political views.

Comment: True, but who is he going to appeal to when discrimination occurs?

Comment: @greatone I'm not at all sure you're correct in this. In making visa decisions, consular officers are tasked specifically with discriminating: will this applicant leave after the visit? Will they behave during the visit? It's not a reach to get to "will this  applicant become a problem?" Subtleties of humor sometimes don't translate easily between political systems, cultures, and language.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica I would agree with you, except OP stated he might want a greencard, in which the state department and DHS can use this website against OP's "morale character". Just ask Neil Young at the moment, he's in the news talking about it.

Comment: @AussieJoe I think you misread my answer and comments. My POV is that there can be some risk in putting one's views/personality/humor/etc out on the internet.

Comment: We are all worried about the risks of criticizing and making fun of politicians. It’s amusing to see that the general perception of the United States has turned from being the beacon of democracy to a pseudo-fascist state where criticism is illegal.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica sorry I had misread your answer. I agree with you 100% and my point was that OP didn't really specify visa category. Different visas have different background checks, my apologies. +1 from me.

Comment: @AussieJoe No worries, we're good.

Comment: @greatone Yes, it's a sad change for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Recently a [Palestinian](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.aljazeera.com/amp/news/2019/09/palestinian-student-harvard-allowed-entry-attempt-190903130512787.html) guy who applied for Harvard has been in trouble when a CBP officer saw his Facebook account and the friends of the guy (not himself) shared anti US-propaganda stuff, and despite of it not being a crime, since it was done outside the US (that's not the only reason), CBP officers, power abusers as they were, shouted aggressively against him in a room asking for explanations and eventually sent him back to Palestine, but in an other instance the guy won a sort of appeal and he succeeded to get at Harvard in time.

An advice that I might give to you, is that if you have a website that parodizes about the US, just don't tell them that you have and end of the story, because you'll only get in trouble due to some US officials patriotic bigotry, and moreover if you don't tell them that you hold that side, on which basis can they suspect if you have any website whatsoever? You're not bringing it.

Another advice, if you have any other account, just log out from your phone and then re log-in after, because they'll make your life hell for every silly thing they may not like either for personal reasons or political ones. Just play smart.

EDIT: Send the link to your job employer and delete it from the portfolio, you don't need to show your project but only to say that you're good in that field. It's also in interest of you not getting copied and getting succeeded over unjustly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100987/discussion-on-answer-by-abdul-will-i-put-my-us-visa-chance-in-risk-if-i-make-a). All further comments here will be deleted.